# Julia not modifying argument after ccall

Tags: julia

Any idea why this function does not modify the 'eta' parameter but returns the expected value?

```
function str2et!( date::String, eta::SpiceDouble )
    ptr = convert(Ptr{ConstSpiceChar}, date)
    et = Array(SpiceDouble,1)
    ccall((:str2et_c,"/home/don/.julia/v0.3/cspice.so"),Void,(Ptr{ConstSpiceChar},Ptr{SpiceDouble}),
                ptr,
                et )
    eta = et[1]
end
```

Comment: Just to clarify: [*Functions that modify their inputs have names that end in `!`*](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.3/manual/variables/#stylistic-conventions), but this is just a naming convention and has no impact on the behaviour of the function. Here, naming your function `str2et!`, with an exclamation mark at the end, does not make it mutable.

Comment: ... I meant *mutating*, not *mutable*.

Comment: The following compiles but does not work.  The initial value of zero is replaced by the 2 but the ccall does not modify the v field.  `type Mutable
    value
end
convert( ::Type{Mutable}, v::Float64) = v

function returnViaDoublePtr()
    angle = Mutable(0.0)
    angle.value = 2
    ccall((:raxisa_c,libNasaSpice),Void,
        (Ptr{Float64},),
        pointer_from_objref(angle) )
    return angle.value
end`

Comment: I fat fingered something and delete the previous response.  I'm sure this is a huge stackoverflow gaffe.  I'm very sorry.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is similar to the following

```
function f(x)
  x=1
end
```

The function does not *modify* the argument, but *replaces* it.

```
y=2
f(y)
y     # Still 2 -- no side effect
f(2)  # Equivalent to f(y)
```

If you want the value to be modified, you can define your own (mutable) type.

```
type Result
  value
end
function g(x::Result)
  x.value = 1
end
y=Result(2)
y.value # This is 2
g(y)
y.value # This is now 1
```

In this example, of course, it would be clearer to return a value.

Comment: OK I understand that only declared types are mutable.  However, I'm trying to interface with some C-language routines that return values using double* arguments.  if you replace the x.value=1 in your g() function with ccall( (:gc,"somelib",Void,(Ptr{Float64},),(&x.value) ) value is not modified.  Nor can you pass &x neither can you take pointer(x)

Answer (score 0):

Making a mutable type is not the answer; however making a one element array does work, but doesn't seem very efficient (code_native on the following function yields a couple screens of assembler)

```
void raxisa_c( double* x ) {
   *x = 3;
}   

function returnViaDoublePtr()
    angle = Array{Float64}(1)
    ccall((:raxisa_c,libNasaSpice),Void,
        (Ptr{Float64},),
        angle )
        return angle[1]
end
```